# Laravel MongoDB combining raw select count and group by

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

I was wondering if I can do this with mongodb aggregate. I have a dataset of 
[image]

And I am trying to achieve this kind of result or anything close that I can loop into
[image]

What I have right now is this:

```
$collegeGender = FormData::raw( function ( $collection ) {
        return $collection->aggregate([
                ['$sortByCount' => [
                    '$mergeObjects' =>[
                        '$details.college',
                        '$details.gender'
                    ]
                ]]
            ]);
    });
```

But it is displaying an error:

```
$mergeObjects requires object inputs, but input "M" is of type string
```

Here is a sample of my collection data

```
{
   '_id': '5d5d77de54f57118ac003b46',
   'details': {
      'age' : 'M',
      'college' : 'College 1',
   }
}
```

I also don't know if I am using the aggregate function correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

**'age'** and **'college'** are not objects, they're just string fields, so you can't merge them using **$mergeObjects** instead you should use **[$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/)**